# Objective-C: Async/Background POST without using delegate method?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsurlconnection

I need to make some POST calls to my server, but I need to not block the main thread. As I understand, `NSMutableURLRequest` and `NSURLConnection` are not thread safe, so it is best to use the async method of `NSURLConnection`.

My question about this is, how I can package it up nicely into a method, instead of having to use the delegate method?  I would prefer to do:

```
NSData *returnedData = [Utility postDataToURL:@"some string of data"];
```

This is how it is easy done with the following method:

```
[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:serviceRequest returningResponse:&serviceResponse error:&serviceError];
```

It is so nice keeping everything within one method, then just having my data returned from it!

Are there any block based methods for this? It becomes an issue when I need to write methods for about 50 different calls and each one needs to use the same delegate method. Am I going about this the wrong way?

This will only need to be for iOS5.

Comment: You say you don't want to block the main thread, but what you said you want to do is very clearly synchronous, i.e. it will block the main thread (or at least, the thread you're calling it from).

Comment: That is an example of how easy I want to be able to return the data.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

iOS 5 adds `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:` which does what I think you want. I've got my code set up to use that if available, but to fall back on performing a synchronous fetch on a background GCD queue and hopping onto the main thread with the result if it doesn't. The latter will be less power efficient but it's just to maintain legacy support.

```
if([NSURLConnection respondsToSelector:@selector(sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:)])
{
    // we can use the iOS 5 path, so issue the asynchronous request
    // and then just do whatever we want to do
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
        queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
        completionHandler:
        ^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
        {
            [self didLoadData:data];
        }];
}
else
{
    // fine, we'll have to do a power inefficient iOS 4 implementation;
    // hop onto the global dispatch queue...
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0),
    ^{
        // ... perform a blocking, synchronous URL retrieval ...
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSURLResponse *urlResponse = nil;
        NSData *responseData =
            [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&error];

        // ... and hop back onto the main queue to handle the result
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
        ^{
            [self didLoadData:responseData];
        });
    });
}
```

In production code you'd actually check the `error`s and HTTP response codes (as a server 404 response is probably just as much an error from your point of view as a connection failure), obviously.

Comment: I am making an iOS 5 app so this works perfectly!  Thank you!

Comment: Is it best to set the queue to [NSOperationQueue mainQueue] rather than my own use with name?

Comment: It's up to you really. I used `mainQueue` because I do some UIKit stuff in the completion handler — the queue you're identifying is where you want the completion handler to occur, so if you want that to happen in the background then pass in your alternative queue.

Comment: Oh really. Ok, so if in my completion handler, I want to update the UI, then I need to use `mainQueue`?

Comment: UIKit work should be performed on the main thread as a rule, but if you wanted to do something like an expensive parsing operation followed by an interface update, it'd make sense to do your completion handler on something other than the main queue and then to jump onto the main queue or thread just to post the UI updates.

Comment: Ok, I understand all that, I just wanted to make sure I followed you.  Thanks again.

Comment: How can I get something outside the scope of the blocks? Such as, I want to return the `NSData` response outside of the block. I tried `__block NSData *data = nil;` but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

`iOS 5.0 >` you can use sendAsynchronousRequest method look at [NSURLConnection Class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and it uses blocks. If you want to support `iOS 4.0 >` too then you have to write one of your own block based Asynchronous URL loading which is fairly easy to write. You are better off by using [MKNetworkKit](https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKNetworkKit).

*but I need to not block the main thread. As I understand, NSMutableURLRequest and NSURLConnection are not thread safe, so it is best to use the async method of NSURLConnection.*

You don't want to do Synchronous network connection it blocks thread whichever it is called from (its even worse if its main thread). You can do Asynchronous network connection on main thread. If you want to do call NSURLConnection on non-main thread then have to create a RunLoop on that thread (if you don't then the delegate methods of NSURLConnection never gets called).

Comment: Although the rest is basically the same as my answer, I'm not sure I agree with the final sentence; this is something you can implement for 5 or 4 in about 50 lines of code so incorporating a large third-party library doesn't sound like it'd make the poster better off, especially given the support and testing ramifications.

Comment: @Tommy For this specific task, I agree that you don't need a third party library. Reason I was recommending using that is going forward if you want to add more features to your Utility class like easy way to handle REST parameters, image caching, etc. although you can keep adding features based on your requirements, your design can get complicated and these third-party frameworks comes handy.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem pre-5.0 so I made a little class to handle the NSURLConnection delegate protocol and offer callers an interface with closures:

BetterNSURLConnection.h

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSURLRequest *request;
```

BetterNSURLConnection.m

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSURLConnection *connection;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSHTTPURLResponse *response;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSMutableData *responseData;

@property (copy, nonatomic) void (^completionBlock)(id, NSHTTPURLResponse *);
@property (copy, nonatomic) void (^errorBlock)(NSError *);
```

... You can add typedefs to make those block signatures prettier...then:

```
@synthesize connection = _connection;
@synthesize response = _response;
@synthesize responseData = _responseData;
@synthesize completionBlock = _completionBlock;
@synthesize errorBlock = _errorBlock;
@synthesize request=_request;


- (void)startWithCompletion:(void (^)(id, NSHTTPURLResponse *))completionBlock error:(void (^)(NSError *))errorBlock {

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

    self.completionBlock = completionBlock;
    self.errorBlock = errorBlock;
    self.responseData = [NSMutableData data];

    NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:self.request delegate:self];
    self.connection = connection;
    [self.connection start];
    [connection release];
}
```

... then do the delegate like this:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)aConnection didReceiveResponse:(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response {

    [self.responseData setLength:0];
    self.response = response;
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)aConnection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {

    [self.responseData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)aConnection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
    self.errorBlock(error);
    self.connection = nil;
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)aConnection {

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

    if (self.response.statusCode >= 400) {
        self.errorBlock(error);
    } else {
        // i do json requests, and call a json parser here, but you might want to do something different
        id result = [self parseResponse:self.responseData];
        self.completionBlock(result, self.response);
    }
    self.connection = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a facade method to op-queue an internal worker which issues the synchronous call. Depending on the rate at which you send the calls, it might work. Example:

```
// Presented in @interface
-(void)sendPostRequest {
   // Last chance to update main thread/UI
   NSInvocationOperation *op = [[[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(sendPostRequest_internal) object:nil] autorelease];
   [opQueue addOperation:op];
}

// Hidden in @implementation
-(void)sendPostRequest_internal {
   NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

   NSURLRequest *request = // yadda, you might use NSURLMutableRequest
   NSURLResponse *response = nil;
   NSError *error = nil;
   NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:response error:error];

   // process data, retain things as needed, post results using performSelectorOnMainThread:

   [pool release];
}
```

It works pretty well for my purposes but you might need to delve a little deeper in to the async stuff, which really isn't too bad.